# Issue with editing data within a list box using multiple forms

Tags: c#, forms, editing

In my program I allow the user to select a student record from the list box, when they hit the edit button a new form opens. This form displays the id and mark of the student they have selected. I am required to let the user edit that mark and update the list box. I am having trouble letting the user edit, and would appreciate any advice on this. (I am having trouble figuring out what to do when I have the user's data inside the edit form)

I'm not allowed to use LINQ, so a solution or advice on how to do it without it would be greatly appreciated.

Main form:

```cs
private void btnEditMark_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string[] s_rec_arr;

    if (lstMarks.SelectedIndex == -1) {
        MessageBox.Show("please select a student");
    } else {
        ModuleData.s_rec = lstMarks.SelectedItem.ToString();
        s_rec_arr = ModuleData.s_rec.Split(':');
        ModuleData.s_id = s_rec_arr[0];
        ModuleData.s_mark = s_rec_arr[1];
        editMark myEditRecordForm = new editMark();
        this.Hide();
        myEditRecordForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Edit form:

```cs
public partial class editMark : Form {
    public editMark() {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        txtStudentID.Focus();
    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Hide();
        Form1 myForm = new Form1();
        myForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void editMark_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        txtStudentID.Text = ModuleData.s_id;
        txtMark.Text = ModuleData.s_mark;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any type of object to a list box, not just strings. Create a student class and add `Student` objects to the listbox. Or maybe you prefer to use your `ModuleData` class. But in any case, you don't need to use `s_rec` with a colon-separated string.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Mark { get; set; }

    // Required to make to have the list box display useful information about students.
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Id = {Id}, Mark = {Mark}";
    }
}
```

Now add a parameter to the edit form's constructor to be able to pass the student

```
private Student _student;

public editMark(Student student)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Remember the student
    _student = student;

    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

    txtStudentID.Text = student.Id;
    txtMark.Text = student.Mark;
    txtStudentID.Focus();
}
```

In the editform, if you do `Form1 myForm = new Form1();`, this will create a new instance of `Form1` instead of of using the existing hidden one.

Remember that a class is a reference type, therefore it is not necessary to pass the student back to the first form, because this one also has a reference to the same student. Only update its properties

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _student.Id = txtStudentID.Text; // Only id the Id is editable.
    _student.Mark = txtMark.Text;

    Close();
}
```

In the main form

```
private void BtnEditMark_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstMarks.SelectedIndex == -1) {
        MessageBox.Show("please select a student");
    } else {
        var student = (Student)lstMarks.SelectedItem;

        // Pass the student as to the edit form
        var myEditRecordForm = new editMark(student);
        Hide();
        myEditRecordForm.ShowDialog(); // The code pauses here until the edit form is closed.
        Show(); // Doing this here prevents you from having the edit form knowing about Form1.

        // To display the changes.
        lstMarks.Items[lstMarks.SelectedIndex] = student;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Oilver, Thanks so much for answering my question! Your solution seems to make alot more sense, Although the code is running it is having trouble with the: var student = (Student)lstMarks.SelectedItem; line. When i run my program i have to first select the mark in the list then click edit, when i do this it crashed due to this line of code

Comment: Of course you have to add items of type `Student` to the listbox. E.g.: `lstMarks.Items.Add(new Student { Id = "1", Mark = "A" });`. **No `ToString()`!** I don't know how you did it. If you assigned the `DataSource`, then you must assign it a collection of type `Student`.

Comment: i read the student ids and marks from a text file. I am really confused on how to go about fixing this issue, when you say the lstmark.item.add(new student.. i dont know where to put it! really sorry for being a tosser here i am really greatful of your help!

Comment: Assuming that each line of the file contains one student record, then convert each line into a student (using split as before) and store them in a `List<Student>()`. `var studentList = new List<Student>();` Something like this `string[] rec = line.Split(";"); studentList.Add(new Student { Id = rec[0], Mark = rec[1] });`.